# Question on the Second Axiom of the First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Where the axiom 2 of the first-order logic in the textbook*A Mathematical Introduction to Logic, 2nd Edition by Enderton* states that:

$$\forall x \alpha \longrightarrow \alpha_t^x, \text{whenever }x \text{ occurs free and }t \text{ is substitutible}$$

My question is, why must it be that $x$ occurs free?

Comment: In the text is it not written that $x$ is *free* in $\alpha$. But if not so, there is nothing in $\alpha$ to be replaced wit term $t$.

Comment: Example: $\forall n (n \ge 0) \to (1 \ge 0)$. If $x$ is not free in $\alpha$ we have that the antecedent will be e.g. $\forall n (0=0)$ which is quite useless.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA But what if here $x$ has no free occurence? Say $\forall n (\forall x (x\cdot n \geq 0) \rightarrow (1 \geq 0))$

Comment: Are you referring to $∀x(x⋅n≥0)$? If so $∀x(x⋅n≥0)^x_t$ is $∀x(x⋅n≥0)$.